# "POST /home_tests/10/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 In an if/else condition, only else is triggered

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I want to make a questionnaire. There is a column with the correct answer from the admin. When voting, it checks against the 'answer' field and stores the votes that matched in 'correct_votes' and the rest in 'votes' . For reconciliation, there is a condition 'if', 'else'. Also, for my understanding, I made it to print 'correct' if the voices with 'answer' converge and 'not correct' if they do not converge. But for some reason, when voting, it always prints 'not correct' and votes are not recorded in 'correct_votes' even when they are the same as 'answer'. But 'else' always works and voices are recorded there.

```
view.py 

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'home_tests/question.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        if selected_choice.votes == question.answer:
            print('correct')
            selected_choice.correct_votes += 1
            # selected_choice.save()
        elif selected_choice.votes != question.answer:
            print('not correct')
            selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_tests:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

```
models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    objects = None
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True, blank=True)


class Choice(models.Model):
    DoesNotExist = None
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    correct_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I try vote and became:

> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
> [09/Jan/2023 18:49:27] "GET /home_tests/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2591
> [09/Jan/2023 18:49:28] "GET /home_tests/10/ HTTP/1.1" 200 785
> not correct
> [09/Jan/2023 18:49:40] "POST /home_tests/10/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [09/Jan/2023 18:49:40] "GET /home_tests/10/results/ HTTP/1.1" 200 521

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVRgU.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more information